# One file writer for multiple classes (fast)

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter, writer

I am working on a heuristic which aims at a short runtime/calculation time. To retrieve the results, I need to write them to a file.
The writing is done by different classes, but they should all write to the same file and I guess they should only use one writer.

I have been using the `Logger` class, but I don't like the output style (with the time stamp and stuff). I rather want to create files that I can easily parse (eg. JSON files). I should probably use a `BufferedWriter` because fast runtime is crucial. But I don't know how to make a writer accessable by all classes. Maybe something like a static writer class?

Edit: I'm not using the Thread interface.

Comment: And when do you .close() it?

Comment: Also, how fast is "fast"? How much do you expect to write per second?

Comment: I close it after the calculations are done. Is that when the file is actually written? Because I only care about the calculation time of the heuristic which ends before .close().

Comment: And you will do it only once in your entire application? What do you ues as a mechanism to divide the work?

Comment: Yes, at the moment my idea is to simply print the result once, after the heuristic is done. Hence, the performance of the writer probably won't even change that much. The solution consists of multiple objects and it would be handy to have each object write it's own information, ie. print of the solution class writes some lines and then calls print of each containing object.

Answer (score 0):

file is exclusive resource and can not be used in multi threaded fashion , for the problem you mentioned you have two approaches

1. As you already mentioned you are using logger, you can continue doing that and the output can be changed as per your need via the logger pattern you define for the said class ([Log4j Formatting Patterns](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm) ). However
   for Printing JSON output you can simply customize the message you are writing to json and save it.
2. Implement your own file writer as a wrapper to existing ones (BufferedWriter ), which will let you write to the same file , ensuring the shared resource(file writer in this case) is controlled properly among different threads
     A. Doing this you have two choices, either make the writer exposed methods as static and use them as needed.

   B. Create a common instance of this writer class and inject it to all the consumer classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a logging framework, but reconfigure it to not print out timestamps and stuff, but only the string you want to log.

Then just create the exact string representation you need, and log that.

For logback you would need a logback.xml file in your classpath looking like (adapted from http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Other logging frameworks use similar approaches.  Use the SLF4J API so you can choose your backend freely.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best logging engines is [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

For native Java Logger though, you can create a custom Formatter and set it to your FileHandler eg.

```
fileHandler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
```

for the formatter class use something like this

```
public class CustomFormatter extends Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        //write your custom JSON message when logging
        //use a fast JSON library such as Boon or Jackson when writing to your Log
        return record.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Singleton design pattern. You can have a StringBuffer (which is thread safe) and define a maximum size for your StringBuffer and include a BufferedWriter in your Singleton class. All your classes can write to the StringBuffer defined in your singleton and as soon as the StringBuffer hits the maximum size you defined for it, write the StringBuffer to your file using the Writer and empty the StringBuffer for the next batch of stuff you want to write to the disk

Comment: That's a waste; and it is only operations on the `StringBuffer` itself which are synchronized. It is not exactly the same as being thread safe ;)

Comment: Yes its only the StringBuffer that is thread safe and I was thinking its only the StringBuffer that is exposed to other classes, and the Singleton itself has a private writer which takes care of writing to the disk. Sorry I'm a newbie, can you explain why its a waste?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write JSON in a file and be able to add entries from various threads and parts of the application the following approach may work.

- Create a class that can receive your log statements. This can be in the form of POJOs that describe your log messages (which will later be JSON). Let's call the class `AsyncLogger` for now...
- In `AsyncLogger`, wrap a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` that will be used to store all log messages.
- Make sure that all producers of data (calculations) have access to the same instance of `AsyncLogger`.
- Create a different thread which continuously reads entries from the queue.

  - Convert every entry to JSON by e.g. using [the Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Check out the `ObjectMapper`.
  - Append JSON entries to a file e.g by using the Java 7 `Files.write` methods.

This pattern offers an async way of processing these entries which ensures that your calculations are not disturbed by I/O from the logging framework. Furthermore, it uses well known libraries for handling JSON transformation.